# Apex to JSON string

Tags: apex, json

Can some one please help me write the Apex class to generate the JSON string as in the below specific format: Start with static header node and then the Array of records.
[image]

The first node ('parent_record') values are static string and the second node is the Array of records from the query result. I was able to generate the child records node with follwoing APex but not sure how to add the parent_record to this and get it All together :

Here is the Apex class that used to generate the Child Records section

```
public class GenerateJSONData {
 
public static void generateJSONFormatDataWithArray(){
    
     
    for(Account acc : [Select Id, oldId, Name from Account where Id in ('001XX' , '0017XYYYY')])
    {
     
        
        
   
    JSONGenerator jsGen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
    jsGen.writeStartObject();     
    jsGen.writeFieldName('records');
    jsGen.writeStartArray();
       
            jsGen.writeStartObject();
            jsGen.writeStringField('ConId', acc.Id);
            jsGen.writeStringField('Name',acc.Name) 
          
            jsGen.writeEndObject();
        
        // Second record 
            jsGen.writeStartObject();
             jsGen.writeStartObject();
            jsGen.writeStringField('ConId', acc.Id);
            jsGen.writeStringField('Name',acc.OldId) 
            jsGen.writeEndObject();
   
    jsGen.writeEndArray();
    jsGen.writeEndObject();
    String jsonData = jsGen.getAsString();
     
    System.debug('json format Data==> ' + jsonData);
        
    }
   
}
```

}

This code generated the following JSON format:

```
 "child_records":[
{
  "ConId":"12345", 
  "Name": "John"    
},
{
   "ConId":"1537", 
  "Name": "Mark"     
}
```

]

But I need as below: Can someone help  ?

[image]